# Oracle POSIX support for REGEXP_LIKE

Tags: oracle, posix

The [REGEXP_LIKE documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/ap_posix001.htm) seems to indicate that POSIX character classes are supported by Oracle.  When I run the following two queries I expect the latter to return a subset of the former, since `[:alpha:]` is a superset of `[A-Z]`.  Instead I get no results when using the `[:alpha:]` version.

I see that POSIX support was added in 10g, but we are running 11g release 2.

Query 1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT offer_id FROM fop WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (offer_id, '^01[:alpha:].*');
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT offer_id FROM fop WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (offer_id, '^01[A-Z].*')
```

Comment: The `.*` at the end of your pattern doesn't do anything except make a little bit more work for the regex engine.

Comment: Are you saying REGEXP_LIKE tries to find the pattern within the field instead of trying to determine if the field matches the pattern?

Comment: no, I'm saying that `.*` at the end of your regex means "match anything or nothing", and is therefore not useful.  `^ora.*` will match the same inputs as `^ora`, no more and no less, except that the former will cause the regex engine to inspect the each input all the way to the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use double square brackets for this kind of character sets:

```
SELECT DISTINCT offer_id FROM fop WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (fop.offer_id, '^01[[:alpha:]].*');
```

Comment: "square brackets":
[: Bracket
(: Parenthesis
{: Brace

Answer (score 3):

in other uses of posix regex, the `[:alpha:]` is a separate "token" that still needs to be inside the char class brackets, so try

```
 SELECT DISTINCT offer_id FROM fop 
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (fop.offer_id, '^01[[:alpha:]].*');
```

IHTH